# Telethon account gets muted by spambot for trying to send a message into a group

Tags: telethon, sendmessage

My script sends messages to groups. It works on some groups, but for some reason the account gets muted INSTANTLY on some other groups for trying to send even the first message for 3 days. And I get all group information as Request SendMessageRequest. It cant be spam or the message itself. This is my code:

```
api_id = 123456789
api_hash = 'API_HASH'
try:
    with TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('group', 'my_message'))
        sleep(10)
        
except:
    client.disconnect()
        
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

This is the output I get when the account tries to send a message:

```
Request SendMessageRequest(peer=InputPeerChannel(channel_id=123456789, access_hash=-123456789), message='my_message', no_webpage=False, silent=None, background=None, clear_draft=False, noforwards=None, update_stickersets_order=None, reply_to_msg_id=None, top_msg_id=None, random_id=6399888382386879515, reply_markup=None, entities=[], schedule_date=None, send_as=None) had missing message mapping Updates(updates=[UpdateReadChannelInbox(channel_id=123456789, max_id=16456611, still_unread_count=0, pts=22916302, folder_id=None), UpdateNewChannelMessage(message=MessageEmpty(id=16456611, peer_id=PeerChannel(channel_id=123456789)), pts=22916302, pts_count=0)], users=[], chats=[Channel(id=123456789, title='Channel', photo=ChatPhoto(photo_id=5918253080787401965, dc_id=4, has_video=False, stripped_thumb=b'\x01\x08\x08\xcf\x0c\xbeV07g\xad\x14QL\x0f'), date=datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 4, 12, 40, 22, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), creator=False, left=False, broadcast=False, verified=True, megagroup=True, restricted=False, signatures=False, min=False, scam=False, has_link=False, has_geo=False, slowmode_enabled=True, call_active=False, call_not_empty=False, fake=False, gigagroup=False, noforwards=False, join_to_send=False, join_request=False, forum=False, access_hash=-123456789, username='channel', restriction_reason=[], admin_rights=None, banned_rights=ChatBannedRights(until_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 5, 12, 40, 26, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), view_messages=False, send_messages=False, send_media=True, send_stickers=True, send_gifs=True, send_games=True, send_inline=True, embed_links=True, send_polls=True, change_info=False, invite_users=True, pin_messages=False, manage_topics=False, send_photos=True, send_videos=True, send_roundvideos=True, send_audios=True, send_voices=True, send_docs=True, send_plain=False), default_banned_rights=ChatBannedRights(until_date=datetime.datetime(2038, 1, 19, 3, 14, 7, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), view_messages=False, send_messages=False, send_media=True, send_stickers=True, send_gifs=True, send_games=True, send_inline=True, embed_links=True, send_polls=True, change_info=True, invite_users=True, pin_messages=True, manage_topics=True, send_photos=True, send_videos=True, send_roundvideos=True, send_audios=True, send_voices=True, send_docs=True, send_plain=False), participants_count=None, usernames=[])], date=datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 4, 12, 49, 43, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), seq=0)
```

Any idea why this is happening on some groups but also not on some other groups? Is there any fix for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well first you need to use a proxy
Secondly, you obviously need to use not one account, but many, and have a proxy for each account